# Omit empty cells in a range when updating a list in Google Forms from Spreadsheet range in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**Background**

I made a Google Form with the purpose of easily adding text items to a Spreadsheet database. Some of the necessary inputs from the Form come from lists or multiple choice, which needs to be updated after new items are added. I looked around for a solution and copied a code from a YouTube video.

**Question**

I am using a range that allows for added items, i.e. A2:A1000, which unfortunately also adds over 900 empty options in my Form list. How do i omit the empty cells to be added to my Form?

**Disclaimer**

I am new to Google Apps Script, so i don't understand much of the 'UpdateListInForm' function. If you know I'm headed in the wrong direction, I would gladly take any advice on optimizing the code.

**Code**

```
//Form ID
var FORM_ID = '1xdmeGyxiQpY00tO_EZMV9jgnUBn8MgiodxcM9NrGHJ8';
//sheet name with a list
var CONTINENT_SHEET_NAME = 'List';
//range of continents
var range = 'A2:A1000'; 
//list id (before run getItemsOfForm function andlook at log CTRL+Enter)
var CONTINENT_ID = '1237940710';

function updateListInForm() {
var values_ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONTINENT_SHEET_NAME).getRange(range).getValues();
values_[0][0] = values_[0][0].toString();
for(var i = 1; i < values_.length; i++){
values_[0].push(values_[i][0].toString())
}
var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
var list = form.getItemById(CONTINENT_ID);
list.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values_[0]);

}                                                                                                                          

function getItemsOfForm(){
var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
for(var i  in items){
Logger.log('id: ' + items[i].getId() + 'title: ' + items[i].getTitle());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to evaluate that the value is not an empty string before pushing it into `values_[0]` array. To do this replace

```
values_[0].push(values_[i][0].toString())
```

by

```
if(values_[i][0].toString()!="") values_[0].push(values_[i][0].toString())
```

A more elegant solution will replacing the use of a hardcoded reference A2:A1000 by someway to get just the range that you need. To do this, you could use [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) among other.

Comment: Your solution works! I would love to use getDataRange(), but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work when i only want the range from one column, in a sheet with multiple columns.

Comment: Regarding the use of getDataRange to get just one column, you will have to use it with getValues() which will return a 2d array. It will help to you to study how to work with multidimensional arrays on JavaScript.